# Joomla - Most Efficient way to force non http:// pre-fixed links to be External

Tags: php, html, joomla

Friends,

I'm looking to find the most efficient way to choose for an anchor tag which will contain a user-submitted link to link to an external site instead of erroneously appending it to the end of the current site url.

```
// Explanation:
```

As many of you know, when writing links in Joomla such as the following:

```
<a href="google.com">Google</a>
```

or

```
<a href="<?=JRoute::_('google.com')?>">Google</a>
```

It appends the href to the current site url.

For example, if my site was http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

And I clicked on either link above it would take me to http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/google.com

...as opposed to what would seem natural, just taking me to google.com

```
// End Explanation
```

Of course I know prepending http:// to the href solves this issue.  However for user-submitted content this means calling a string-based method to check user-submitted links to make sure http:// (or https, etc.) is what starts the url and if not, to append it.

Could someone shed some light on other options for doing this.  I'm hoping to find out if there are possibly better, more efficient methods.

Also, if it turns out that I am doing it the best way possible, then I would love to see what others use for this string function.

Thank you Stackfriends.

Comment: Will they ever be internal urls or would they always be external?

Comment: Well for the sake of learning; what would be your suggestion if they could be either.
Also what would you suggest if they would strictly be external links.

Comment: If it is always external, I would probably do a search for just `//` and if not present tack `http://` to the front of the string. If it could be either, I would probably split it and give a drop down of likely internal places or let them enter a custom (i.e. external) url. Since for the internal you are likely limiting them to either a menu item or a predefined set of places that make sense

Answer (score 1):

That's not a "Joomla" behaviour thats the way URL's are to be resolved as defined by the standard. What you're talking about is how browsers etc are supposed to process a relative or absolute URL.

Changing this behaviour is IMO only likely to result in grief.

> A **URL** is a string that represents an identifier.
>
> A URL is either a relative URL or an absolute URL. Either form can be
>   followed by a fragment.
>
> A **relative URL** is a URL without a scheme. A relative URL must be
>   relative to a base URL.
>
> An **absolute URL** is a URL with a scheme.
>
> A **base URL** is an absolute URL with a relative scheme.

You might want to read more of this at http://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urls

Answer (score 1):

This code will enforce http:// for `$unknownlink` without scheme (protocol):

```
$link = JUri::getInstance($unknownlink);
if (!$link->getScheme()) $link->setScheme('http');
echo JHtml::link($link, $link, ['target' => '_blank']);
```

works in J3.4, not sure about old versions